# How to include the part name in the header of classicthesis scrreprt?

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis

How could I include the part name in front of the chapter name in the header of odd pages within a classicthesis scrreprt document?

The original section in classicthesis.sty reads as follows:

```
% ******************************************************************                
% headlines
% ********************************************************************  
\PassOptionsToPackage{automark}{scrpage2}
\RequirePackage{scrpage2} % provides headers and footers (KOMA Script)
\clearscrheadings
\setheadsepline{0pt}
\ifthenelse{\boolean{@nochapters}}%
    {\relax}%
    {\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}} 
\lehead{\mbox{\llap{\small\thepage\kern2em}\headmark\hfil}}
\rohead{\mbox{\hfil{\headmark}\rlap{\small\kern2em\thepage}}}
\renewcommand{\headfont}{\small}  
%    \DeclareRobustCommand{\fixBothHeadlines}[2]{} % <--- ToDo
% hack to get the content headlines right (thanks, Lorenzo!)
    \def\toc@heading{%
        \ifthenelse{\boolean{@nochapters}}%
        {\section*{\contentsname}}%nochapters
        {\chapter*{\contentsname}}%chapters
        \@mkboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}}
```

It results in a header with the actual chapter name on odd pages and the sections name on even pages. Do I have to include something like `\renewcommand{\partmark}`?
What exactly is `\headmark` doing? Again, the aim is to include the part name (not the number) in the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[parts]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\xpatchcmd{\Part}
  {\ctparttext}
  {\gdef\thisparttitle{#1}\ctparttext}
  {}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\thisparttitle}\relax
    \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}
             {\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}%
  \else
    \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\thisparttitle\relax\ -- #1}}
             {\spacedlowsmallcaps{\thisparttitle\relax\ -- #1}}%
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\clearparttitle}{\gdef\thisparttitle{}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\part{First}
\chapter{Title}
\section{Section}
\kant

\appendix
\clearparttitle
\chapter{Appendix}
\kant

\end{document}
```

You need to remove the part title when you don't want it any more.